# DBD::MySQL: LongReadLen and LongTruncOk

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi, truncate

Have the attributes `LongReadLen` and `LongTruncOk` when using [DBD::mysql](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBD%3A%3Amysql) as driver for the Perl5 Database Interface (DBI) any meaning? I didn't found these attributes in the `DBD::mysql` documentation but I found some example on the internet which uses these attributes with `DBD::mysql`.

Comment: I have used that attribs in large blob reading from mysql db and it worked fine for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you search [dbdimp.c](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/CAPTTOFU/DBD-mysql-4.022/dbdimp.c) I find:

```
 *
 *  Name:    dbd_st_blob_read
 *
 *  Purpose: Used for blob reads if the statement handles "LongTruncOk"
 *           attribute (currently not supported by DBD::mysql)
```

I could not find any reference to longreadlen. Note, I don't use DBD::mysql myself and this was just a quick search in the code.

Answer (score 2):

That is a [DBI attribute](https://metacpan.org/module/DBI#ATTRIBUTES-COMMON-TO-ALL-HANDLES) which applies to all handles.  Its documented in the DBI library.  AFAIK it applies to DBD::mysql and every DBI driver.